# unicode-math and amsmath environments

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math

I'd like to use unicode-math but I've run into some problems. The following mwe, compiles without problems. The aligned environment is used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation} 
    α = \beta^2_i + β^2_i 
\end{equation}

\begin{align} 
    a &= b\\
    b &= c
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

but if I add the following code (using cases environment - defined in amsmath) then I get a segmentation fault

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    a &= b\\ 
    b &= c 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

What I want to ask is if the two packages can be used together (so this is a bug) or if I am going to encounter more problems like this one.

The output of the compilation is [this one](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nNVNdzGR) and here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Px0ChrcH) file.

ps. I know that it is easy to emulate the cases environment.

ps2. Although it must be obvious, I am using xelatex.

UPDATE
I am using TexLive 2010 64bit on Linux

Comment: Are you using the 64bit version of XeTeX?

Comment: At present your example does not compile: it does not load `amsmath` or `unicode-math`. Even if I do, I don't get any α or β in the output, so simply adding them is not enough.

Comment: @Joseph: When loading `unicode-math`, you also need to specify a font (but I agree, the example code is incomplete).

Comment: Your MWE cannot be compiled proberly for me, since `amsmath` is missing, and `unicode-math` is missing. Please put the real MWE here.

Comment: @Caramdir. Not being a user of `unicode-math`, I suspected this might be the case without being sure. However, it's rather the point of a MWE to include such information.

Comment: @Joseph: This preamble should work: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmathfont{XITS Math}`

Comment: @Leo: indeed it does. I'll edit the question to add this in.

Comment: @pmav99. This example works for me with TeX Live 2010 on my Mac (64-bit version of XeTeX) and on Windows (32-bit version). Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I've had problems with unicode-math, 64 bit xelatex *on linux*, and scaleable delimiters so this may well be the same problem.  My workaround was to install the 32bit version of TeXLive and use that instead (whereupon it all worked fine).

Comment: I am using 64bit Linux. The Texlive 2010 net install if it does matter. 
I am sorry about the missing packages, I must have missed them with the copy-pastes somehow...

I updated the original post with the new info. Thank you all for your answers

Comment: I realize this is not the point of your question, but: Your example of how you'd like to use the cases environment is not really that environment's intended use.  For what you have above, an aligned environment is more appropriate (though I suppose cases does come up with pretty much the same thing).

Comment: @Phil : Yeah I know. I just added some code that would be syntactically correct. I didn't want to make the example more complicated.

Comment: @pmav99: I think there's no need to duplicate Philipps's answer in your question. You accepted the answer, and this shows that it helped you to solve your problem. I'll remove that part of your question; please complain if that's not OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Andrew’s hint is correct: the Linux 64-bit version of XeTeX has a regression, see [the bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3053287&group_id=194926&atid=951385). You can either:

1. Wait for the bug fix to propagate to downstream TeX Live (won’t probably happen until TeX Live 2011), or
2. Install the 32-bit architecture. TeX Live supports multiple architectures on Linux:

   ```
   tlmgr platform add i386-linux
   ```

   After that you can place a symlink to the 32-bit `xetex` and `xelatex` executables in a directory which comes early in your `PATH` (e.g. `~/bin`). This way, you can continue using the other 64-bit binaries.
3. Or use LuaTeX instead, which doesn’t have that bug.

Comment: Theoretically, you could also compile XeTeX yourself with that patch applied (though using 32bit XeTeX or LuaTeX is the easier solution).

Comment: @ Philipp : Thank you very much! I'll try the 32bit version.